# Is this normal 9patch behaviour? and how can I avoid it?

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding, nine-patch

I'm working on a search bar that's supposed to stretch full width of the screen, so I'm thinking 9patch rather than 5 different assets, right?

This is what it looks like
[image: This is what it looks like]

9patch asset: 
[image]

- I tried settting android:padding=0dp, also dynamically with setpadding(0,0,0,0);
- I've updated the 9patch to allow content all over the image (the bottom and right lines - at max length)

Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you means that your EditText gets extra padding.
Please set it in Java , not in layout.

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.myedittext);
text.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

View will get extra padding if you set a 9patch background to it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I resized my 9patch asset like so:[image]

And my **theory** is that the 9patch gets split in the middle(horizontally) and the content is inserted, rather than simply surround the content.
So if you have a 10px 9patch and a 10px content, you would get a 20px result, instead of my former belief that it would be something like 12px.

Hope this helps :)

---

P.S. I will vote the correct answer to whomever comes with something more than a **"theory"**